# Can you use Angular-CLI beta 17 on a project created by Angular-cli beta 15

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a created a project using angular-cli beta 15, I would like to upgrade to angular-cli beta 17, would that cause me any problems?

Comment: The approach I have used in this circumstance is simply create a new ng project after having installed angular-cli@latest  ("ng new project-name) then copy over anything from the app folder in the previous project with the exception of app.modules.ts which I reconfig manually

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did that as well couple of times, and I know cli does give you the option with ng init after you install the new cli version, but curious if not doing eitehr will work or not ...

Comment: My understanding is that future versions of angular-cli will have seamless upgrading, but up until now I was just doing full re-installs just to make sure to get all latest goodies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You have to uninstall cli globally first:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

Then remove the project files

```
rm -rf node_modules dist tmp
npm install --save-dev angular-cli@latest
ng init
```

ng init asks you questions to overwrite your current files. Press d to see the difference. Sometimes only installing angular-cli and trying to run ng init doesn't work. If that is the case you can do npm install than install the latest cli. If you have a smaller project, I would try switching that first. Good luck!